# Which square doesn't belong here and why?

Tags: pattern, visual

Which square doesn't belong here and why?

[image]

Comment: I am fine with downvotes. Would appreciate to know the reason so that I could improve the quality of my questions.

Comment: I think this question is original and there is no need to be down-voted. But there are guys who downvotes questions like guessing the next in the sequence and find the odd one out puzzles, claiming that it can have multiple correct answers.

Comment: Downvotes are community indicators for bad quality, a comment is essential only if there is a specific reason, its my downvote and I believe such questions don't contribute to "quality" content in this site - trivial, unsearchable, too broad are some of the reasons

Comment: Lazy, are you ever gonna accept one?

Comment: @warspyking This is something we generally advocate on all SE sites, and that is to NOT use comments to pressure the OP into accepting an answer.  Behavior like that is immature

Comment: @thin I'm not trying to pressure him into it I'm just trying to notify him we're still here through a comment. It's approaches 24 hours, he's got 7 answers, I'm interested to know which is correct.

Comment: The reason to consider this question as too broad is because of this very reason that we have many seemingly equally valid and acceptable answers I dont know why its not earning one more close vote

Comment: Wow! When I posted this, I just thought this was a just simple quiz with a simple answer. @AeJey posted the answer I had in mind right away, but wanted to wait a few more hours to accept it. But it was week end, and I am barely connected on week ends. Come Monday, I am amaze to see all those answers which are at some level acceptable. I can edit my post to filter the correct answer, but it wont do justice to the others who took their time and imaginations to provide angles I have never thought of.

Comment: Why is this open? "Which square doesn't belong?" is a clear example of a vague any-answer-can-be-justified puzzle that is not allowed as per meta discussion and SE policy. See the close reason: "This question may invite speculative answers, as the question is not fully defined. The validity of some answers may be based upon opinion. Good questions for this site have a limited number of objectively correct answers."

Comment: Odd-one-out questions are usually bad, since (unless it's completely obvious) there's hardly ever a single unique answer. As you've seen here from the wide variety of different answers, all to some extent justifiable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer is

> **3 (third square)**

In all the other squares except

> 3rd square, **3 (three) lines** divides the square in to **5 parts**, while in 3rd square **the lines (three lines)** divides it to **6**.

Answer (score 35):

The big orange one. All the others are brown.

It's clearly the odd one out.

[image]

Comment: This wasn't tagged lateral thinking...

Comment: It asks which square is the odd one out. I see 5 squares, one of them is markedly different from the others.

Comment: By this logic I can say my screen is the odd one out -_-

Comment: @warspyking you have a square screen? how peculiar!

Comment: @njzk2 I was just saying that for an example. What if I were using one hmm?

Comment: I could say the square of the intersecting grey lines (you can see it in the dead center) because there isn't any white space inside. Perhaps that's it? But it's not tagged lateral-thinking...

Comment: Why would they label the squares with clear numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) in the first place? Anyway, puzzling is indeed supposed to be fun. :)

Comment: @ir7 - The numbers are purely to distract you.

Comment: Maybe. But they create a context around this puzzle. And one expects an answer out of the box (aka "lateral thinking") within the context. Not out of the park! :)

Comment: @ir7 - Vox Populi, Vox Dei

Comment: True that!!! :)

Comment: If you only see 5 squares, then something's wrong. There are the 4 brown squares, the big orange square, and there are 4 more squares that are outlined in both orange and grey.

Comment: @mdc32 is correct. The answer is still the big orange square though, because it is the only square which is unique in size. This answer still works even if you count the intersections of line thicknesses as 'squares'.

Comment: @mdc32 There... are... FOUR... lights!

Comment: @Michael I think that might be a reference... If it is, I don't understand it. Sorry :P

Comment: @mdc32 indeed it is.  google "picard four lights" for more info.

Answer (score 12):

Only number 1...

> has lines that meet the bounding square at a corner

Only number 2...

> lacks any lines that slant down and to the right

Only number 3...

> (a) divides the square into 6 areas instead of 5, (b) contains two complete intersections, and (c) includes a complete red triangle

Only number 4...

> has no uniquely distinguishing characteristics.  So my guess is 4.

Comment: 4 does have a unique distinguishing characteristic now! The fact that it don't have the others!

Comment: @warspyking [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) may be of interest, for both this and countable infinite sets of squares/elements/other things.

Comment: @hexa That *is* interesting...

Comment: This was my guess. The only one that I thought of at least.

Comment: 4 is the only one who's triangle does not have two sides of the same length.

Answer (score 8):

Answer is

> 3

Because

> 1, 2 and 4

could be a part of representation of

> number 4, mirrored or rotated.
>
>  [image]

But the picture in number

> 3

is different.

Comment: how is it different ? it is still 3 lines intersecting.

Comment: This is what I thought at first too.

Comment: @njzk2, but they did not across throw their intersection. in those 3 lines ended in proper place

Comment: @Rafe: sorry I don't understand what you mean by `they did not across throw their intersection`. 3 lines in a plane either intersect, or 2 of them are parallel. (no figure shows parallel lines, so.)

Comment: @njzk2, my bad! not good in english :-) i mean lines in 3rd square continued *after* their intersection. this is something more that a 4. so 3rd square cannot represent number 4's shape. but you can create number 4 with continuing lines of other squares.

Comment: @Rafe Once you get out of the frame and really consider the lines supporting the line segments (visible in the frame), you can't really choose to stop (hence define more line segments) liberally, can you? :) (That's how I got my answer.) In any case you have my upvote for your imagination power (and correct answer). :)

Comment: no it is not...

Answer (score 5):

I choose

> frame 3 because is the only one that shows the triangle created by the three lines through their pairwise intersections. In all four cases the (non-trivial) triangle exists, but in cases 1, 2 and 4 it is not presented within respective frame. (Edit: note that this is technically equivalent to AeJey's answer that observes the number of parts the frame is split into by the three lines.)

Answer (score 5):

Clearly the odd one out is

> 4.

Graphical explanation

> [image: Explanation]

Wordy explanation:

> 1,3,2 are slices of a bigger picture. 4 does not fit with any of them. Even if we prolongue the lines in 1,2,3 they still fit well in the overall picture.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. What are you saying?

Comment: @anthropomorphic Perhaps it makes more sense now?

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I don't think you're right. I think you could still find a rotation of 4 that would fit in the picture. Also, 1 and 3 don't match up that well.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is;

> Frame 3

For three reasons:

- 1

> When you extend the lines of 1, 2, and 4, they can join in a path of 3 lines which are in broken. You cannot do this with 3.

- 2

> When you look at how many sections of white space there are in 1, 2, and 4 there's 5. In 3 there's 6

- 3

> 3 is the only square, where the lines within the frame make a triangle.

So obviously it has to be the answer stated above!

Comment: I was going to answer three for your reason 1.

Comment: And only 3 shows 2 intersections.